# Does PostgreSQL manages tables inside tables?

Tags: database, postgresql

I was assigned the task to create a simple Database Management System in a class so I looked up Postgres and noticed that the CLI tool (psql) has commands (\d and \l) that output information about the database and columns of a table in the form of tables like when you do a SELECT. So my question is If Postgres manages user tables inside system tables? and that way when you do \d or \l you are actually doing a SELECT on those system tables. This is just to understand if that would be a good way of managing tables in a database or not and just use regular data structures like lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed. You can run psql with `-E` to see the queries it is using.

Then check the [online manuals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html)
The items to search for are "system catalogs" and "INFORMATION_SCHEMA". The latter is a standard way of describing database schemas and should mostly work between different RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that flag

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Postgres uses tables that it creates to manage the tables that you create.

There is [an entire chapter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) in the documentation explaining. To quote:

> The system catalogs are the place where a relational database management system stores schema metadata, such as information about tables and columns, and internal bookkeeping information. PostgreSQL's system catalogs are regular tables.

As mentioned in the [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498505/642706), the SQL standard requires metadata  be provided in some table structures as defined within the standard. These must be housed within a schema named exactly `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Postgres provides that schema and its prescribed tables, but implements them as a [view](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) on the actual system tables. See the [chapter on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) in Postgres documentation.

You can access the metadata, such as to get a list of all the tables you have defined, or get a list of all the columns you defined in a particular table. To do so, perform a query in SQL using `SELECT` like any other query.

- For portability, meaning to write code that works in other database systems in addition to Postgres, query against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.
- For additional details not required by the SQL standard, and for Postgres-specific info, query against the Postgres-specific system tables. Their names all start with `pg_`.